# Div блоки в две строчки с прокруткой вправо и влево

Tags: css, html

Из массива с данными выводится в каждый блок информация. Главный блок ограничен размером 500px и высотой 600px, как сделать, что бы блоки были в два ряда и и когда их много, появлялась прокрутка влево и в право?

Comment: Что значит `блоки в два ряда`? Блоки и вообще любые блочные элементы итак выводятся друг под другом. Если вы имеете ввиду в две колонки, есть несколько способов: `float: left`, `display: inline-block`, `flex-box`, и т.д За прокрутку отвечает свойство `overflow`. В вашем случае, скорее всего требуется `overflow-x: auto`

Comment: У меня есть информация в БД, я вывожу каждую запись  в отдельный div, примерно 10 записей, в свою очередь, эти блоки находятся в общем div, этот "главный" div имеет ограничение по ширине и высоте, так вот, надо, чтобы они выводились эти блоки в две строчки, в одну сроку влазит только 3 блока, нужно, что бы выводил в две строки, а если элементов больше, появлялась прокрутка вправо и элементы добавлялись правее, верхнюю строку и нижнюю.

Comment: Боюсь, что так не получится, по крайней мере без ручного переноса строк. Можно сделать в одну строку, в две - браузер не сможет определить, в какой момент нужно перенести строку, если вы не укажете перенос явно.

Comment: Я кажется понял как, каждые два блока обвернуть еще в один блок и сделать эти блоки уже в одну строку, тогда будет видно что в две строки.